# Every vector space is isomorphic to the set of all finitely nonzero functions on some set

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove the statement in the title, that

> Every vector space is isomorphic to the set of all finitely nonzero functions on some set.

A finitely nonzero function from $X \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ (the field of scalars) is one for which there are finitely many $x \in X$ s.t. $f(x) \neq 0$. Also, this set of functions is made a vector space by defining linear combinations the natural way.

I think the solution hinges on the fact that each $v \in V$ is a linear combination of the basis $\mathcal{B}$, and linear combinations are by definition finite (even if $V$ is inf. dimensional).

My attempt: Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis. Each $v \in V$ is a (finite) linear combination of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. As such the isomorphism can take each $v \in V$ to $f_v : \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ where $f_v$ takes each basis element to its coefficient in the (unique) linear combination representing $v$. $f_v$ is finitely nonzero because only finitely many basis elements have a nonzero coefficient. We could then prove bijectivity....

Is my solution correct? Also, why is "finite" in the definition of "linear combination"? Wouldn't it make sense to have a vector in $V$ equal to, say, the sum of *all* basis elements, even if $V$ is inf. dimensional? I think I know one reason-- a polynomial vector space could have $e^x$ as an element otherwise-- but I'd like to hear others.

Comment: It is important to address the vector space structure of said set $X$, as "isomorphic" only make sense in vector space context (well an algebraic structure).

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt is correct. However, I guess it might be slightly easier to consider the inverse homomorphism $(f\colon \mathcal B\to \mathbb F)\mapsto \sum_{b\in\mathcal B}f(b)b$.

We use "finite" in the definition of linear combination because infinite sums (except when all but finitely many summands are zero -  the expressoin $\sum_{b\in\mathcal B}f(b)b$ is of this kind) are not even defined in general. Even if we restrict to the case of a countable index set, or in fact to good-old well-ordered $\mathbb N$, not all "sums" (which are called series instead of sums for a purpose) work: Within $\mathbb Q$ you cannot "sum" $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac1{n^2}$, within $\mathbb R$ you cannot "sum" $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}n$ or $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}(-1)^n$. Without well-order on the index set, the situation becomes worse, not to mention the case of uncountable index set.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct.

Infinite linear combinations are not such an easy concept as you might think.
Your polynomial example is a good one -- though the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and though $1, x, x^2, x^3, \ldots$ are all independent, an infinite linear combination of these will not be a polynomial.
Another example would be the set of continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then many infinite sums of continuous functions are not continuous or even well-defined.

You may be interested to read about [Schauder bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis), which are (countably) infinite bases for certain kinds of vector spaces. 
For this notion to work your vector space needs to be [Banach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space) -- i.e. it has a norm, and the space is complete under that norm. But unlike with the bases you are used to (called "Hamel bases"), in which everything is a finite linear combination of the basis elements, NOT every space has a Schauder basis. Another caveat is that regardless of how you define infinite sums, not all infinite linear combinations will be defined. For example, take any nonzero vector $v$, and the infinite linear combination $1 v + 1v + 1 v + 1 v + \cdots$ does not have meaning.